# How do extract all the tweets from a data frame given a character vector of "user_id_str" in R

Tags: r, subset

enter image description hereI extracted tweets from Twitter Streaming API in R for a week between certain timeframes. I have a data frame of 42 variables one of which is `user_id_str`. It is of type `Character`. I have a character vector of user IDs with me. What I want to be able to do is get all the tweets associated with the user IDs in the character vector. I am certain that all the user IDs in the character vector are present in the data frame as well.

`timeframe_tue` is a dataset where there are all the tweets of tuesday between 11:00 AM to 13:00 PM.

`common_users` is a character vector with the user IDs I am interested in. It has a length of 93

I tried running the following command and I got a data frame full of NAs with the same number of columns as `timeframe_tue` and 93 rows.

```
 com_tue <- timeframe_tue[timeframe_tue$user_id_str[common_user],]

 timeframe_tue[,"user_id_str"][user_count] –– this didn't work either

 timeframe_tue$user_id_str[timeframe_tue$user_id_str==user_count]–– Neither did this.
```

[This is a sample of how my data frame looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA3kA.png)

Can someone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Can you offer a sample dataframe? Maybe upload it to github?

Comment: Try : `timeframe_tue[timeframe_tue$user_id_str %in% common_users,]`

Comment: there may be multiple tweets from a single user. Does this work for that as well? Or does it only give me the first encountered tweet matching the user id?

Comment: @polka I have attached an image of how my data frame looks like.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a really fast solution based on `data.table`

```
# load library
 library(data.table)

# convert yout data.frame to data.table to speed up the process
  setDT(timeframe_tue)


# filter
  timeframe_tue[ user_id_str %in% common_user, ]
```

You can also make use of the `%in%` operator to correct your solution, like this:

```
 timeframe_tue[ timeframe_tue$user_id_str %in% common_user, ]
```

Comment: That seemed to have done the trick :) . But can you tell me what exactly was the problem with my command? And why is it faster after converting it to data.table? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `data.table` is probably overkill for a 93 row dataframe

Comment: Because of the way `data.table` is built, it is by far the fastest package for data manipulation available today. You can read more about it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) and check a nice [cheat sheet on how to use it here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) @UdayAyyagari, I'm glad my answer worked . I've updated the answer correcting your code

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot @RafaelPereira.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dplyr solution. You really are just looking for the correct "%in%" syntax.

```
library(dplyr)

timeframe_tue = tbl_df(timeframe_tue)    

timeframe_tue %>% filter(user_id_str %in% common_user)
```